# Should all .net 6 apps running in the same App Service be Out of Process?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Traditionally we have a number of .net framework web apps and APIs on azure, with some (mostly our test environment) running in virtual directories of the same App Service.

Now we are converting them to .net 6 / creating new ones I have run into a problem.

The 2nd .net 6 app I have publshed in a virtual directory had the following error:

```
HTTP Error 500.35 - ANCM Multiple In-Process Applications in same Process
```

which was supposedly resolved by changing it to be out of process:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

...but which now returns the following error instead:

```
HTTP Error 500.34 - ANCM Mixed Hosting Models Not Supported
```

So, in .net 6 (and going forwards) do we no longer host apps in virtual directories (as applications), or do they ***all*** need to be out of process? Is being out of process now best practice even if not the default?

Or have I missed something (probably "yes" :) )?